# Sum a range of cells in Excel according to a range (criteria)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-365

cordial greetings

I am trying to obtain the sum of the number of males taking into account an age range that I set previously.

[image: Picture]

For example, I want to know how many males, between the ages of 3 and 12, there were in 2018. For this, I have proposed the following formula:

`=SUM(SUMIF(B2:V2,{"Mens_3","Mens_4","Mens_5","Mens_6","Mens_7","Mens_8","Mens_9","Mens_10","Mens_11","Mens_12"},B3:V3))`

One of the many problems I have is that this formula is quite long, and on the other hand, if I want to modify the age range, for example: men between 5 and 10 years old, I have to modify the criteria of the formula.

I have tried with the SUMPRODUCT function, but I did not succeed.

Could you please let me know if there is a simpler way to perform the calculation I require?

Thank you for your attention

Comment: Just as a comment: You can edit Excel functions in Notepad, so they have hard returns, to make them more readable. If you then copy paste them into one cell, they will retain that page-layout or page-format. They do not need to be one long string.

Answer (score 1):

Try the formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((NUMBERVALUE(REPLACE($B$1:$O$1,1,5,""))>=NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(B$7,FIND("-",B$7)-1)))*(NUMBERVALUE(REPLACE($B$1:$O$1,1,5,""))<=NUMBERVALUE(REPLACE(B$7,1,FIND("-",B$7),""))),$B$2:$O$2)
```

Drag it to fill the other cells.

You can shorten it

```
LET(x,NUMBERVALUE(REPLACE($B$1:$O$1,1,5,"")),y,FIND("-",B$7),SUMPRODUCT((x>=NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(B$7,y-1)))*(x<=NUMBERVALUE(REPLACE(B$7,1,y,""))),$B$2:$O$2))
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Great graphics! Nice, with what software did you make that, if I might ask?_____


BTW, not to be overly nit-pickish here, ;) but your first solution is **191** characters long, and your shortened 2nd, **154** characters.  The **OP's** original formula is 120 characters. So, 159% and 128% respectively. :P :D

Comment: @GwenKillerby The software is Licecap (you can search for it, plus it is free). Regarding the characters count, yes right now, mine is longer (even the shorten one). However if the OP has more columns, mine might be shorter in that case (I might be wrong though).

Comment: Sadly the link i found had a version with a virus. see here https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/3d2f620d177ecdfa4ed75b4230dd1f7eb43cc07d2ed351ea409dcbcb7ab145fd?nocache=1

Comment: @GwenKillerby Not sure if I should trust Gridinsoft on this one as there are the only that detect a possible virus. Bitdefender and Kasperky that I use don't detect anything and I trust them more. However you should be the one taking the edcision on whether to download and use it :)

Comment: Dear @ReddyLutonadio thank you very much for your valuable information, it has been useful and has helped me to get an alternative way to find a solution to what I have been looking for, I appreciate your collaboration and attention to solve my doubts

The solution I found with your help, I share it in the following line

`=SUMPRODUCT((MID($B$1:$O$1,1,FIND("_",$B$1:$O$1)-1)="Mens")*(MID($B$1:$O$1,FIND("_",$B$1:$O$1)+1,10)+0>=MID(B$7,1,FIND("-",B$7)-1)+0)*(MID($B$1:$O$1,FIND("_",$B$1:$O$1)+1,10)+0<=MID(B$7,FIND("-",B$7)+1,LONG(B$7))+0)*($B$2:$O$2))`

Comment: @CamilaSanchez You are allowed to answer your own question. It will allow others to see  your (solved) formula. `MID($B$1:$O$1,FIND("_",$B$1:$O$1)` is used multiple times. You can reduce the length of your formula with the LET function.

Comment: Dear @ReddyLutonadio, I am not very familiar with the LET function, could you perhaps, if you are so kind, help me a little with this solution using this formula, and if possible send me information about how to use the LET function, I appreciate your valuable assistance.

Comment: @CamilaSanchez Your formula with the LET function will be `=LET(x,MID($B$1:$O$1,FIND("_",$B$1:$O$1),SUMPRODUCT((x-1)="Mens")*(x+1,10)+0>=MID(B$7,1,FIND("-",B$7)-1)+0)*(x+1,10)+0<=MID(B$7,FIND("-",B$7)+1,LONG(B$7))+0)*($B$2:$O$2)))`. The LET function (if you have Excel 365) allows to assign a variable (in this case `x`) to a calculation (`MID($B$1:$O$1,FIND("_",$B$1:$O$1)`). The calculation will be performed only once (instead of multiple times in the case of your formula), assigned to x and reused. Making your formula shorter, easy to read and the whole calculation SUMPRODUCT... quicker.

Comment: Dear @ReddyLutonadio you are very kind, thank you for your collaboration, I did not know the LET function, now I will approach it in more detail and I will put it into practice, a big hug.